# When calling a SOAP Service parameter is passed as null

Tags: c#, java, soap, service, web

I am a little bit newbie about those web, and SOAP service issues. My problem is as follows:
I have a web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class QlogisticIntegration : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod(Description = "Qlogistik.")]
    public QlogisticResultEntity DoAccountingForProducts(QlogisticInputEntity pMsg)
    {    
    MessagingProcessor mProcessor = new MessagingProcessor();

    ResponseMessage respMsg = null;
    QlogisticResultEntity resultMessage = new QlogisticResultEntity();
    DateTime vToday = Global.GetChannel("QLOGISTIC").Today;
    Intertech.Core.Framework.Context.CurrentContext.Branch = Global.GetBranch(9019);
    Decimal exchangeRate = FxRatesQuery.GetRates(9019, "T", "D", "A",
                            pMsg.CurrencyCode,
                            vToday);

    CqlogMessage msg = new CqlogMessage();
    msg.QlogInputEntity = pMsg;

    .
    .
    .
    .
    return resultMessage;
}
}
```

And here is how i call it via java:

```
public tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticResultEntity DoAccountingForProducts(tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticInputEntity pMsg) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    if (super.cachedEndpoint == null) {
        throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
    }
    org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();        
    _call.addParameter(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/", "pMsg"), new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/", "QlogisticInputEntity"), tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticInputEntity.class, javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode.IN);
    _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
    _call.setReturnType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/", "QlogisticResultEntity"), tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticResultEntity.class);
    _call.setSOAPActionURI("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/DoAccountingForProducts");
    _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
    _call.setScopedProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setScopedProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
    _call.setOperationStyle("wrapped");
    _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/", "DoAccountingForProducts"));
    _call.setReturnQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx/", "DoAccountingForProductsResult"));

    java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {pMsg});

    if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
        throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return (tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticResultEntity) _resp;
        } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
            return (tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticResultEntity) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_resp, tr.com.intertech.core.QlogisticResultEntity.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I debug both webservice and the java application(actually a web site), and when I make the request to the web service, it hits the breakpoint in debug mode of the web service. However the parameter pMsg is passed as null althoguh I can see its content and it is not null during debugging in eclipse, before calling the web service.

All of the properties of the pMsg object is initialized and a value is given, and as you see the parameter names, and types are same.

Here is the related wsdl:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    - <wsdl:types>
        - <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost:30000/QlogisticIntegration.asmx">
            - <s:element name="DoAccountingForProducts">
                 - <s:complexType>
                     - <s:sequence>
                         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pMsg" type="tns:QlogisticInputEntity" /> 
                         </s:sequence>
                 </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I could not get to anywhere from here, I used fiddler but since I am using a complex datatype i could not see it on the fiddler, Actually I could not set fiddler to localhost on port 30000(the port web service is  published), and I have very little idea how to do it.

If anyone gives and opinion or a little help, it will be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't really know how to call SOAP from java, but just to verify -  does the namespace in QName require the trailing slash? The missing parameter could be because of invalid namespace.

Comment: above java code does the stuff, I do not also have the deep info about it. 
I tried removing the last slash in the URI. Now the error message is: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (5, 5).

Comment: after rebuilding both client and service projects, it started to work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> does the namespace in QName require the trailing slash? The missing
>   parameter could be because of invalid namespace.

just quoted the comment so it could be accepted as answer :)